# Problems with SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

I have issues with loading playlists using the SPAsyncLoading class. Sometimes the call does not return at all, sometimes after a long time.

I use the following code to load a playlist from a url:

```
NSString *playlistUrl = [Config instance].playlistUrl;
[SPPlaylist playlistWithPlaylistURL:[NSURL URLWithString:playlistUrl] inSession:[SPSession sharedSession] callback:^(SPPlaylist *pl) {
    playlist = pl;
    playlist.delegate = self;

    [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:playlist then:^(NSArray *array) {
        NSLog(@"playlist loaded");
    }];
}];
```

I use the following code to load all of the users playlists:

```
SPPlaylistContainer *userPlayLists = [[SPSession sharedSession] userPlaylists];

[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:userPlayLists then:^(NSArray *result) {

    SPPlaylistContainer *userPlayLists = (SPPlaylistContainer*) [result objectAtIndex:0];

    [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:userPlayLists.playlists then:^(NSArray *result) {
          NSLog(@"playlists loaded");
    }];
}];
```

In case of loading all of the users playlists sometimes 0 playlists are loaded, sometimes all playlists are available but the last waitUntilLoaded won't return.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

On this line: `[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:userPlayLists.playlists then:^(NSArray *result) {`

…replace `userPlayLists.playlists` with `userPlayLists.flattenedPlaylists` — folders aren't `SPAsyncLoading` compliant.

Please be aware that `+[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:then:]` has been removed from the latest builds of CocoaLibSpotify, and only `+[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:timeout:then:]` remains. This is to ensure you *always* get a callback even if stuff isn't loading.

Possible reasons things won't load:

- The network is being slow and/or is down.
- The metadata service is slow and/or down.
- The playlist service is slow and/or down.

Since Spotify is an internet service, you need to be responsive to problems when loading metadata and playlists. `+[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:timeout:then:]` helps you by giving you a list of things that have and haven't loaded if not everything has completed loading when the timeout occurs.

Comment: Okay, so probably the playlist service was slow / down when I was testing the app. I tested it again today and it is working fine right now without modifying the code.